# Constructing a fair schedule that includes all combinations of employees

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, symmetry

Suppose there are $n$ people, and a task that must be done at each time step that requires exactly $k \leq n$ people to be completed.

We want to create a "fair" repeating schedule that assigns $k$ people to perform the task at each time step. The schedule must meet a few requirements to be fair:

1. Each of all ${n \choose k}$ combinations of people must be scheduled for at least one time stamp.
2. Each combination of people appears in the schedule the same number of times as all other combinations of people.
3. Each *individual* person's schedule is identical, modulo a shift in the start time. In other words, each person has the same list of intervals between their assignments.

How could we find a shortest schedule that meets these requirements? It seems somewhat related to [block design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design).

### Examples

For example, if $n = 3$ and $k = 2$, then a shortest schedule would be:
$$(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)$$

If $n = 4$ and $k = 2$, then the shortest schedule I've come up with is:
$$(1, 3), (1, 2), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 4), (2, 3), (1, 4)$$

For this one, person $1$'s *individual* schedule is:
$$(Y, Y, N, N, Y, N, Y, N, Y, N, N, Y)$$
person $2$'s schedule is:
$$(N, Y, N, Y, N, Y, N, N, Y, Y, Y, N)$$
which is identical to $1$'s but shifted three spots left. Similarly, persons $3$ and $4$ have the same schedule shifted 6 and 9 spots left, respectively.

### Equivalent Formulation

Another way to think about this problem is as a "spoke design" problem. We want to design a set of spokes that can be overlaid on itself $n$ times to fill each slot exactly $k$ times. For example, in the $n = 4$, $k = 2$ case, a fair schedule would consist of the following "spokes" represented by blue dots:

[image: Person 1's Assignments]

This set of spokes can be overlaid on itself 4 times (in different orientations) to fill each point along the circle exactly twice, while representing all possible combinations an equal number of times (in this case each combination appears twice).

[image: All Assignments Overlaid]

Comment: I agree that your problem is very, very related to block design. That means you may find there are no "fair" schedules for a given $n,k$--or to follow the standard notation of block design, a given $v,k$.

Comment: That said, you have an extra constraint about each person's schedule being the same up to shifting in time.

Comment: There should always exist at least one fair schedule. I’ll construct one:

Comment: Take all combinations and arbitrarily order them in some schedule $S$. Then append $S$ $n-1$ more times to itself to create a bigger schedule of length $n*|S|$, but each time you append $S$ shift its persons 1 to the left. So the first appended $S$ looks like the one before it, but with all 1’s replaced by 2’s, all 2’s replaced by 3’s, etc. The second appended $S$ has all 1’s replaced with 3’s, all 2’s with 4’s, etc. etc.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right that there should always be one, but the normal parameter $\lambda$ kinda goes out the window with that extra constraint. :) For instance, a $(4,2,1)$ design exists with $b=6: 12, 34, 13, 24, 14, 23$. But those six blocks can't be put into a periodic design, which is why you needed $12$... days? segments? Not sure.